# How to assign an object's values from the data of an API request?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, oop, fetch

I am a beginner web developer and I have questions related to the API request.
I made an API request in an asynchronous function called footData, which will return an array of numbers (e.g., [0, 2, 4, 12, 32, ...]) in the success variable.
Then, I must insert the values of this array in the object my data object.
So, my data [0] .success must be my success [0].
The problem is that I can't get the success data out of the asynchronous function.

Here is my code:

```
const footData = async () => {
  const url = "xxxxxx";
  const bearer = 'xxxxxx';

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": bearer
    }
  })
  const json = await response.json();
  const fData = json.tabela;
  const success = fData.map(obj => obj.aproveitamento)
  for (let i = 0; i < success.length; i++) {
    console.log(success[i]);
  }
  return {
    success
  }
}

footData(data);
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rerender the React Dom when you call function outside the Component like that. Then I put some useState, useEffect usage to make the call to API and rerender the layout after getting the data from API

```
const HistoryTable = () => {
  const [tbData, setTbData] = useState(data)
  useEffect(()=>{
     const newData = await footData(data);
     setTbData(newData.success)
  },[])
  return (
    <div className="table-responsive text-nowrap historyTable">
      <Table columns={columns} dataSource={tbData} pagination={false} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default HistoryTable
```

Comment: This really helped me a lot!
Thank you so much!
I'll post my full solution as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

You can do things in `.then()`:

```
 fetch(url, {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": bearer
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Instead of logging the response, you can assign the value's to an array or do anything else with it.

```
.then(data => { arrayForSuccessData = data} )
```

See the documentation for [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).